# Boxed function factory (higher order function) in Rust results in "call expression requires function"

Tags: rust

I want to pass a function factory, i.e. a higher order function, but I get `call expression requires function` errors.

```
// function that takes 4 f32 generates a function which maps one f32 to another f32
// DOESN'T WORK
type FunctionFactoryType = Box<dyn Fn(f32, f32, f32, f32) -> (dyn Fn(f32) -> f32)>;

fn abc(x: FunctionFactoryType) {
    (*x)(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
    // ^ call expression requires function
    // expected function, found `(dyn Fn(f32, f32, f32, f32) -> (dyn Fn(f32) -> f32 + 'static) + 'static)`
}
```

If I use a "regular function" (not higher order), i.e. `Box<dyn Fn(f32 -> f32)>` it works. Am I missing something or is this a Rust error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call compiles if you make the outer `dyn Fn` return `Box<dyn Fn>` instead of `dyn Fn` directly:

```
type FunctionFactoryType = Box<dyn Fn(f32, f32, f32, f32) -> Box<dyn Fn(f32) -> f32>>;
```

(Note that you don't need `(*x)(...)` to call a `Box<Fn...>`, you can just use `x(...)`.)

The return type of `dyn Fn(...)` isn't valid because `dyn Fn` is unsized, you have to put it behind a reference or a smart pointer. Since it's in return position, it can't be a reference, so `Box<dyn Fn(f32) -> f32>` is what you want. (This is also covered in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html#returning-closures).)

The error message is quite cryptic, presumably as a result of the flaw in the declaration preventing `Box` from implementing `Fn(...)`, which made it a non-function. Interestingly, if you comment out the call altogether, compilation succeeds even with the original incorrect definition of `FunctionFactoryType`.

Comment: I've now filed a [bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83189) about the diagnostics for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the return type of your function is not `Sized`, e.g. this works:

```
type FunctionFactoryType<O: Fn(f32) -> f32> = Box<dyn Fn(f32, f32, f32, f32) -> O>;

fn abc<O: Fn(f32) -> f32>(x: FunctionFactoryType<O>) {
    (*x)(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
}
```

It also works to put the returned function into a `Box<Fn(f32) -> f32>`.

I can't answer *why* it states this isn't a function expressions.